# Sharing twitter app

Tags: twitter

I have created an app in my personal twitter account by logging into https://dev.twitter.com/apps, I am then able to access the twitter account from my java webapp (using springsocial).

Now I would like to include this app for a different twitter account but I can't seem to find how. If I try to recreate the app on the other account it tells me the name has already been used. Is there a way of using an existing app that was created in another twitter account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It's not possible. You have to register under another name. Its twitter's rules, one account, your app.